# How to align brand + links on navbar in twitter bootstrap(the latest version V3.0.0)

Tags: navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just need to know where to change it to align everything including the brand to the left. I can't for the life of me find it anymore in the CSS. I want to make the navbar skinnier and everything align from the far left, and not in the center of the webpage. :/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-left navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="something.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forums <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this helper class `class="pull-left"` that could possibly help you.
I've missed it the first times, [bootstrap navbar-component-alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment).

However, if you want to align a dropdown menu item in the navbar, you should use 'dropdown-menu-left' in place of the 'dropdown-menu' class [bootstrap dropdown-alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment).